# How to remove control of main window from parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my main window code it has one browse button and this button also display on user control but I don't want to show that button and space taken by that button in user control [image]

```
<Window x:Class="Take_Out_Info.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Take Out Info" Height="auto" Width="auto" 
        Closing="Window_Closing" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="menuitem" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" Padding="17,0,17,0" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Uid="Border_38">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"  Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Uid="ContentPresenter_33"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="#b5d2fc">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid  Grid.Row="0" >
            <Menu Name="browsemenu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Opacity="1" Height="50" Background="#1389e4"  >
                <MenuItem x:Name="browse" Width="140" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource menuitem}" Click="browse_Click" Height="30"  Background="white" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="black">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock  Width="90" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="CENTER" Foreground="#1389e4"  FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" ><Run Text="Browse"/></TextBlock>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>                    
            </Menu>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="DetailsControl" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

this image is my main window [image]

This is my user control code

```
<UserControl x:Class="Take_Out_Info.BrowseFile"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:adorners="http://gu.se/Adorners" 
             Height="auto" Width="auto">

    <Grid Background="#b5d2fc">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid   Width="auto" Background="#1389e4">
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Browse" Name="btnBrowse" Click="btnBrowse_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="27" Width="140" Background="White" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Search" Name="btnSearch" Click="btnSearch_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="190,0,0,0" Height="27" Width="140" Background="White" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Reset" Name="btnReset" Click="btnReset_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="370,0,0,0" Height="27" Width="140" Background="White" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" />
            <ContentControl x:Name="DetailsControl" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="0" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Width="auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox Name="txtDayfind" adorners:Watermark.Text="Search Day Here" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="120"/>
            <Button Name="btnDayfind" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="110,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnDayfind_Click">
                <Image Source="002-search.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnDayReset" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="157,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnDayReset_Click">
                <Image Source="001-multiply.png"></Image>
            </Button>

            <TextBox Name="txtDatefind" adorners:Watermark.Text="Search Date Here" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="120"/>
            <Button Name="btnDatefind" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="121,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnDatefind_Click">
                <Image Source="002-search.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnDateReset" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="170,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnDateReset_Click">
                <Image Source="001-multiply.png"></Image>
            </Button>

            <TextBox Name="txtTimefind" adorners:Watermark.Text="Search Time Here" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="120"/>
            <Button Name="btnTimefind" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="121,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnTimefind_Click">
                <Image Source="002-search.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnTimeReset" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="170,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnTimeReset_Click">
                <Image Source="001-multiply.png"></Image>
            </Button>

            <TextBox Name="txtLatfind" adorners:Watermark.Text="Search Lat Here" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="120"/>
            <Button Name="btnLatfind" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="121,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnLatfind_Click">
                <Image Source="002-search.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnLatReset" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="170,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnLatReset_Click">
                <Image Source="001-multiply.png"></Image>
            </Button>

            <TextBox Name="txtLongfind" adorners:Watermark.Text="Search Long Here" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="120"/>
            <Button Name="btnLongfind" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="121,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnLongfind_Click">
                <Image Source="002-search.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnLongReset" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="170,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnLongReset_Click">
                <Image Source="001-multiply.png"></Image>
            </Button>

            <TextBox Name="txtAddressfind" adorners:Watermark.Text="Search Address Here" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="-15,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="120"/>
            <Button Name="btnAddressfind" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="121,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnAddressfind_Click">
                <Image Source="002-search.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnAddressReset" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="170,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnAddressReset_Click">
                <Image Source="001-multiply.png"></Image>
            </Button>

            <TextBox Name="txtTypefind" adorners:Watermark.Text="Search Type Here" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="120"/>
            <Button Name="btnTypefind" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Margin="121,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnTypefind_Click">
                <Image Source="002-search.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnTypeReset" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Margin="170,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" Click="btnTypeReset_Click">
                <Image Source="001-multiply.png"></Image>
            </Button>

        </Grid>

        <TabControl  x:Name="tabControl1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="auto" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEvaluation}" TabStripPlacement="Top" >
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Height="auto" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Day"  Binding="{Binding [Day]}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Date" Binding="{Binding [Date]}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Time" Binding="{Binding [Time]}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Lat" Binding="{Binding [Lat]}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Long" Binding="{Binding [Long]}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Address" Binding="{Binding [Address]}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding [Type]}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: 3]

What to do for getting output like image 3.I to want to remove that browse button which is in blue color and also space has taken on user control for that window.
User control takes the only controls of user control and not of the main window.
It can only show user-control controls and not of main windows control when opening on user control window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should remove this below Grid from XAML source:

```
<Grid Background="#b5d2fc">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition  Height="50"/>
<RowDefinition Height="auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid  Grid.Row="0" >
<Menu Name="browsemenu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Opacity="1" Height="50" Background="#1389e4"  >
<MenuItem x:Name="browse" Width="140" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource menuitem}" Click="browse_Click" Height="30"  Background="white" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="black">
<MenuItem.Header>
<TextBlock  Width="90" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="CENTER" Foreground="#1389e4"  FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" ><Run Text="Browse"/></TextBlock>
</MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
</Menu>
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Row="1" >
<ContentControl x:Name="DetailsControl" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

If No , You can set 0 for `<RowDefinition  Height="50"/>`

Comment: Do you removed this Grid or  `<TextBlock  Width="90" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="CENTER" Foreground="#1389e4"  FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" ><Run Text="Browse"/></TextBlock></MenuItem.Header>`  from your code? 
maybe I did not understand your problem well.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable visibility of browse MenuItem's on click event(browse_Click) of mainwindow xaml page like below

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
browse.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: I also try this button is invisible but the space assign for that button is remains